# Scrum / Visual Studio Team Services add custom capacity activity

Tags: azure-devops, scrum

In visual studio online, I need to add Code Review activity when configuring team members capacity , could this be done ??
i am using a custom process inherited from scrum

[image]

Comment: I'd consider "code review" to be a part of development.

Comment: that's true, but i am thinking of separating it to different activity for classify code review tasks from development tasks and for better capacity assigning and reporting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t custom Team Capacity Activity in VSTS, there is a user voice that you can vote and follow. [VSTS Custom Team Capacity Activity as well as custom status](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13828185-vsts-custom-team-capacity-activity-as-well-as-cust)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to change that list an VSTS currently.

You would have to change the allowed values for the field Activity. Since this is a system field it is not supported in a standard VSTS account.

If you imported the collection from on-prem TFS you can do that through customizing the process template ([hosted XML process](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/import-process/customize-process)).